# Moving files older than X days not working in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$dt         = Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$logFolder  = '\\192.168.20.151\user_backups\Veeam_Logs'
$source     = "$logFolder\*.log"; $destination = "$logFolder\Backup Logs [$dt]"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination -Force
Move-Item ($source | Where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) $destination -Force
```

I'm trying to move *.log files in its current directory (so not folders & not recursive) to its sub-folder but only those log files that are older than 7 days. For some reason the above isn't working as it's still copying files that are 20 days old. There's no error.

Also I don't want it to give me any errors if there are no *.log files to copy (or at least when there's no match). -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue didn't work for some reason.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you mean you want to copy files that are ***younger than 7 days*** because older than 7 days and 20 days old are matching conditions.

Comment: You are not doing a directory query for `$source`. You need `$source = Get-ChildItem "$logFolder\*.log"`. You need a `FileInfoObject` returned in order to see the `LastWriteTime` attribute.

Comment: Sorry I meant it was copying all *.log files even those newer than 7 days. I made the $source change as you suggested but nothing is being copied even though there's one file that's older than 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform a condition against `LastWriteTime` attribute, you need to first return a `FileInfoObject`. A path string passed into `Move-Item -Path` won't have the attribute. You can do something like the following:

```
$dt         = Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$logFolder  = '\\192.168.20.151\user_backups\Veeam_Logs'
$destination = "$logFolder\Backup Logs [$dt]"
$source = Get-ChildItem -Path "$logFolder\*.log" | Where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination -Force
Move-Item -LiteralPath $source -Destination $destination -Force
```

`$source` here performs all the conditional logic. It is unclear if you want files newer or older than a certain date. If you want files that are newer than `$date`, you will want to use `LastWriteTime -gt $date`. If you want files older than `$date`, you will want to use `LastWriteTime -lt $date`.

---

You can have `-Path` value perform the logic, but you must pass in an expression.

```
$dt         = Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$logFolder  = '\\192.168.20.151\user_backups\Veeam_Logs'
$destination = "$logFolder\Backup Logs [$dt]"
$source = Get-ChildItem -Path "$logFolder\*.log"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination -Force
Move-Item -LiteralPath ($source | Where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -Destination $destination -Force
```

Comment: Yes I want files older than 7 days moved to the subfolder. I tried your latter code but it still doesn't move the files. It just creates the folder. For testing purposes I tried both -gt and -lt.

Comment: Do you want the last modified date of a file to be checked or the creation date? Also, what PowerShell version are you running (output of `$psversiontable.psversion.Tostring()`)?

Comment: I just ran this against a test directory, and it worked as expected. So either you are running a different PowerShell version that behaves differently or `LastWriteTime` is not what you expect it to be. If `Get-ChildItem -Path "$logFolder\*.log" | Where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)` outputs more than you expect, then your condition needs to be changed.

Comment: PS version is 5.1.14409.1018. I'm getting the expected result for $source in your first example with the | Where LastWriteTime filter. I tried it manually from the command line. But for some reason it's just not moving those files to the $destination. I tried your code line by line and the subfolder is always empty and the source file is not moved. The file that should've moved hast a LastWriteTime of 2/29/2020   7:36 AM which is older than 7 days now.

Comment: $source = Get-ChildItem -Path "$logFolder\*.log" | Where LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) lists the expected file and is older than 7 days: LastWriteTime of 2/29/2020   7:36 AM I just don't understand why it's not moving it with: Move-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Force

Comment: In what you just posted, you are missing a backslash --> `Get-ChildItem -Path "$logFolder\*.log"`.

Comment: I just realized that when I paste this line here it strips the backslash. Another words the backslash is not missing.

Comment: What if you add a backslash to the end of your destination path? Maybe there is a file on the destination side that matches the directory name.

Comment: No the destination doesn't even exist. It is created when it gets to New-Item. But I found the problem. I just don't have a solution. The *.log filenames start with a date like [03-14-19] filename.log and if I remove the brackets then the file is moved as expected.

Comment: Change your `move-item` to use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`.

Comment: Yessirree Bob! Nice one. I've never seen that one yet. Thank you very much for all your help!